# Does jquery .add() remove duplicates from the new list?

Tags: jquery

I have been wondering and couldn't find in documents. Does merging jquery list of of jquery objects using `add()` results in duplicates if some elements are the same in those two lists or jquery `add` take cares of it

Comment: what did it do when you tried it?

Comment: googling, reading documentation, and stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery does not add duplicates to the list.

```
var $test = $('.comment-copy')
$test.add($test)
```

does not duplicate the list

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the **union** of those elements and the ones passed into the method.

So it's a union (removes duplicates), not a simple concatenation.